# Cannot move Keyboard up when UITextView is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I try to make UITextField and UITextView moving up when a keyboard pops out.
However, I find that it works only for UITextField but not for UITextView.
Is there anything I missed?

Both textFields and textViews are delegated.

Here's my code:

```
var activeField: UITextField?
var activeView: UITextView?

func registerForKeyboardNotifications()
{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWasShown(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillBeHidden(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}


func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification)
{
    var info : NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().size
    var contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)

    self.scrollview.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollview.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
    if let activeFieldPresent = activeField
    {
        if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField!.frame.origin))
        {
            self.scrollview.scrollRectToVisible(activeField!.frame, animated: true)
        }
    }

    if let activeViewPresent = activeView
    {
        if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeView!.frame.origin))
        {
            self.scrollview.scrollRectToVisible(activeView!.frame, animated: true)
        }
    }
}


func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification)
{
    var info : NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().size
    var contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.scrollview.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollview.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField)
{
    activeField = textField
    registerForKeyboardNotifications()
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField)
{
    deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
    activeField = nil
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    activeView = textView
    registerForKeyboardNotifications()
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
    activeView = nil
}
```

Comment: Are textview delegates getting called? Does keyboard appear when you tap on textview?

Comment: @ArunGupta Yes, it is called. The keyboard appears when I tap on textview. I discover one difference when I tap on textfield and textview. When I tap on textview, the keyboard appears, but the function keyboardWasShown cannot be triggered to call. Would this be the reason? Thanks!